# regex with {} in PHP: scan the world in bracket and put to array

Tags: php, regex

I have a paragraph in format like :

```
" Hello {name} , I have receive from {email}, from {date} . THanks"
```

I want to to scan and get all the worlds in {} such as `{name}`,`{email}` etc.. and put them in an array with format : `array("{name}","{email}","{date}")` in php . Please help me with preg_match function (? )

Comment: to get more than one match, you need to use `preg_match_all` function.

Comment: Read it here for basic functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{[^}]+}
```

Try this.See demo at regex101.

http://regex101.com/r/sA8iT4/3

```
$re = "/{[^}]+}/";
$str = "Hello {name} , I have receive from {email}, from {date}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```